# How to fix this rotted exterior window sill corner?

Tags: window-frame

[image]

I scraped the rotted wood away. Was wondering if I should start with expanding foam. How should I repair?

Comment: Cut and remove past the rot.  Replace with new wood.  Neat exact cuts can use wood glue to hold.  prime and paint to finish.

Comment: expanding foam will fill the hole, but it has no structural strength